# Parsing array multidimension from ajax to controller in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a dynamic table and i want to send in controller by ajax. I have code ajax like this :

```
$(".save").click(function(e){
    var items = new Array();
    $("#list-item tr.item").each(function () {
        $this = $(this)
        var ref_item_id = $this.find("#ref_item_id").val();
        var ref_pic_id = $this.find("#ref_pic_id").val();
        var price= $this.find("#price").val();
        var qty= $this.find("#qty").val();
        items.push({ ref_item_id : ref_item_id, ref_pic_id : ref_pic_id, price: price, qty : qty});
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '<?php echo base_url("transac/save")?>',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({'items': items }),
        success: function (data) {              
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            alert(obj.lenth);
        },
        error: function (result) { alert(result); }
    });
})
```

now, how get data in controller and save in table database. My Controller like this :

```
public function penjualan_save(){
    $items = $this->input->post("items");
    // next code ???
}
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first thing, your don't need JSON.stringify({'items': items }), just use:

```js
data: {'items': items },
```

**and in your controller**, just create a model and pass your post data into it, for example:

```php
public function penjualan_save(){
    $items = $this->input->post("items");
    $this->load->model('model_name');
    $this->model_name->insert($items);
}
```

then you need to define a function for **your model**, like this:

```php
public function insert($data)
{
    // if you didn't call database library in autoload.php
    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
}
```